# Problemas ao enviar e-mail php

Tags: php, envio-de-email, email

Estou tentando enviar e-mails para listas específicas cadastradas no banco de dados, com a função mail do php porém o e-mail não é enviado.
**Qual pode ser o erro?**

**Abaixo o script para envio de e-mails:**

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    //realiza a conexão com o banco de dados
    require_once("includes/conexao.php");
    //monta o corpo da mensagem
    $corpo                  = file_get_contents("$_POST[mensagem]");
    //lista de e-mails que será enviada
    $lista                  = $_POST["lista"];
    //remetente (e-mail de quem envia)
    $remetente              = $_POST["remetente"];
    //pega o domínio do remetente
    $dominio                = substr(strrchr($remetente, "@"), 1);
    //assunto da mensagem
    $assunto                = $_POST["assunto"];

    //realiza o envio dos emails
    $sql                    = "SELECT DISTINCT email FROM dados WHERE lista = '".$lista."'";
    $query                  = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
    while($exibir           = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        //headers
        $destinatario       = $exibir["email"];
        $headers            = "MIME-Version:1.1"."\n";
        $headers           .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"."\n";
        $headers           .= "To: <$destinatario>"."\n";
        $headers           .= "From: Teste de envio"."\n";
        $headers           .= "Reply-To: <no-reply@$dominio>"."\n";
        $headers           .= "Return-Path: <$remetente>"."\n";
        $envio              = mail($destinatario, $assunto, $corpo, $headers);
    }
```

**Obs.: Não é retornado nenhum erro.**

Comment: Onde está testando este envio, localhost ou no servidor?

Comment: Estou testando no servidor, Kinghost

Comment: Normalmente host compartilhado não permite envio em massa ou longas execuções de scripts. Alguns até permitem envio de email em massa mas com limitações (200, 300 por dia), por exemplo. Consulte o seu provedor e verifique as condições do plano assinado

Comment: o smtp ta configurado?

Comment: @RafaelFerreira Sim, o SMTP está configura corretamente

Comment: Obrigado @DanielOmine Informação muito importante. Vou verificar, talvez seja isso.

Comment: o erro pode ser a falta do parâmetro `-f` também: `mail( $destinatario, $assunto, $corpo, $headers, '-f'.$remetente );` em sistemas baseados no _sendmail_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente tente forçar a mostrar os erros:

```
<?php

    ini_set('display_errors','On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Pode ser também que a funcão mail(), esteja desabilitada na kinghost, por vários motivos, um deles é spam.

Aconselho a utilizar o PHPMailer, para o envio via SMTP, é mais seguro e seu e-mail não correrá o risco de cair na caixa de spam também.

Comment: É errôneo afirmar que o e-mail não cairá na caixa de SPAM, haja vista que, isso depende de muitos fatores que envolvem a configuração da maquina de onde o e-mail está sendo enviado, o histórico de e-mails do IP remente, o conteúdo do e-mail, seu título, IP reverso e muitas outras coisas.

Comment: Muito obrigado @Ívini, porém uso o mail() na kinghost para outras aplicações sem problemas. Vou dar uma pesquisada no PHPMailer